# Why I can not see the my png file?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to R and today I try to save my figure by following the code:

```
powerplant <- ggplot(Emission.l, aes(x = Year, y = value, fill = variable))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') +
  ggtitle(Emission.Aerosol$Facility.Name)+
  ylab("Emission(Tons)")+scale_fill_discrete(name = '', labels = c('SO2 (tons)', 'NOx (tons)')) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2003:2015)

png(file = paste0(Emission.Aerosol$Facility.Name,".png"),
     width = 439, height = 266, units = "px",pointsize = 12,
     bg = "transparent")
dev.off()
```

Then, I can see the png file was created in my folder but it was only a white figure.
Please let me know what is wrong with my code.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: why not just use ggsave()?

Comment: It helps if you provide a link to a) the dataset you are working on... I support Richards recommendation...

Comment: That's works ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I personally find it is cleaner to separate out the construction of ggplot()'s as detailed below, this makes it easier to play with the construction of the ggplot as you build the plot grammar, then you can choose how you save / print it.

I hope this helps.

```
  require(ggplot2)

  gp <- ggplot(Emission.l, aes(x = Year, y = value, fill = variable))
  gp <- gp + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
  gp <- gp + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') 
  gp <- gp + ggtitle(Emission.Aerosol$Facility.Name)
  gp <- gp + ylab("Emission(Tons)")
  gp <- gp + scale_fill_discrete( name = '', 
                                  labels = c('SO2 (tons)', 'NOx (tons)'))
  gp <- gp + scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2003:2015)

  powerplant <- gp
  print(powerplant)  
  dev.off()
```

Comment: @ Pete Jarvis Thanks a lot ! But the way, do you know how to set the color of the bars? For example, I would to set SO2  in red and NOx in blue. I appreciate your advice which is very helpful to the new user!

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I check that resources before but kinds of get lost. That is my first time to make those plots.  Thank you for your hints but after adding the code : I get the  "Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (26): fill".

Comment: The code is `Emission.l <- melt(Emission.Aerosol, id.vars = 'Year', 
                   measure.vars = c('SO2.tons', 'NOx.tons'))

gp <- ggplot(Emission.l, aes(x = Year, y = value, fill = variable))
gp <- gp + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
gp <- gp + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge', fill=c("red","blue"))
gp <- gp + ggtitle(Emission.Aerosol$Facility.Name)
gp <- gp + ylab("Emission(Tons)")
gp <- gp + scale_fill_discrete( name = '', 
                                labels = c('SO2 (tons)', 'NOx (tons)'))
gp <- gp + scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2003:2015)`

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
png(...)
print(powerplant)
dev.off()
```

or just use `ggsave`. The `png` command doesn't actually put any plots on disk. It simply creates a blank png file that is then ready to receive a plot. After you run it, you send `ggplot` or `lattice` graphics to the device by `print`ing them. Base graphics commands will be sent directly to the device.